# Starting a GCDWebServer in a macOS/Cocoa app freezes the app

Tags: gcdwebserver

When I start a simple GCDWebServer server from a macOS/Cocoa app (not command line) the app freezes ("Application Not Responding" + beach ball).

In AppDelegate:applicationDidFinishLaunching method:

```
let webServer = GCDWebServer()

webServer.addHandler(forMethod: "GET", path: "/hello", request: GCDWebServerRequest.self) { request -> GCDWebServerResponse? in
    print(request)
    return GCDWebServerDataResponse(html:"<html><body><p>Hello World</p></body></html>")
}

webServer.run(withPort: 8080, bonjourName: "Hello World Web Server")

print("Visit \(webServer.serverURL) in your web browser")
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the `webServer.run()` API: it won't return and is designed for command line tools. Use `start()` instead.